# How to combine Dataframe of sets by checking intersection of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, set

I'm trying to combine a Dataframe of sets by checking 2 columns

This is my dataframe, the data inside every cell is python set()

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['COMPARE0'] = [set([1,2,3]),set([3,4,5]),set([6,7]),set([10,11]),set([12,13])]
df['COMPARE1'] = [set(['a','b','c']),set(['d','e']),set(['c','f']),set(['g','h']),set(['h','i'])]
df['GET0'] = [set(['aaa']),set(['bbb']),set(['ccc','ddd']),set(['efg','hii']),set(['efg','hiii'])]
df['GET1'] = [set(['000']),set(['111']),set(['222']),set(['333','444']),set(['555'])]
```

**Input:**

[image]

I would like to combine all rows based on set intersection result of COMPARE0 and COMPARE1

If any intersection is found, then combine the all
columns

**Desired Output:**

[image]

I'm using set() at the moment, but can be lists as well

Any help is kindly appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Got a quick & dirty fix for you, which you'd have to optimise yourself.

**Code:**

```
data = dict(map(lambda x: (x, []), df.columns))  # this will hold combined data
keys = ['COMPARE0', 'COMPARE1']  # attrs to consider for intersection check

for i, row in df.iterrows():

    for key in row.keys():  # add values to a list based on column name
        data[key].append(set(row[key]))  # typecast to handle lists

    if len(data[keys[0]]) >= 2:  # time for intersection check
        for key in keys:
            intersection = data[key][-2] & data[key][-1]  # update check status
            if intersection:
                break

        if intersection:
            for key, value in data.items():
                # pop last two entries, combine them & send them back to the same list
                data[key].append(value.pop() | value.pop())

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Expected output:**

```
                COMPARE0            COMPARE1                  GET0             GET1
0  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}  {a, d, f, c, e, b}  {ccc, bbb, ddd, aaa}  {111, 222, 000}
1       {10, 11, 12, 13}           {i, h, g}      {efg, hiii, hii}  {333, 555, 444}
```

PS: I'd love to see how it'd be done using just Pandas, please share if you get that right.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution, However,
In the [# time for intersection check] Section, the script only checks in the [-1] and [-2] position
The script should check [-1] with [all]